# How to configure log4j2.xml for QuickFIX/J logs?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, quickfixj

I'm using QuickFIX/J version 2.1.1 and log4j2 on my project.
Quickfix logs to path FileLogPath specified and the log file not rolling by daily.
How can I configure the log file stored in daily with log4j2.xml configuration?

Comment: I have the same problem.. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You currently cannot configure by way of QuickFIX/J configuration.

What you can do, is create your own logging strategy:

1. Create a log factory class, extending `quickfix.LogFactory`
2. Create a log class, extending `quickfix.Log`
3. From the `quickfix.LogFactory.create( SessionID sessionID )` method, return a log class instance from the class you created in step 2. Take note of the `quickfix.SessionSettings` instance for settings like log path and log heartbeats.
4. In your log class (see step 2), delegate to log4J functionality to have daily rolling
5. Pass an instance of your log factory class (see step 1) when you create your `quickfix.Initiator` instance.

Logging should then be done using an instance of the logger class you created in step 2.

Note that QuickFIX/J is open source; you can always peek at implementations of `quickfix.LogFactory` and `quickfix.Log` to get some examples. For instance `quickfix.FileLogFactory` and `quickfix.FileLog`.